# Permutation/Combination with license plates

Tags: combinations, permutation

Question, with a California license plate, it has #LLL### where L = Alphabet.  I know with the combination is 10^4 * 10^3 for all possible solution.  How about if I excluded a certain word, such as "FSS", where any combination of car license plate would not include the word "FSS".

How do I go upon this? I can still use the letters, but the three can't be together.  Its throwing me for a loop. Do I use permutation to exclude the repetition word?  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT- the # = digits.  So from 0-9, there are ten possibilities, sorry didn't clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only so many ways you can have FSS in a string of seven characters.

```
FSS####
#FSS###
##FSS##
###FSS#
####FSS
```

So there are five different license plates with the string FSS in them. If there is no constraint on the four numbers, that means you have 9,999 different license plates for each position of "FSS".
You would want to subtract 9,999 * 5 from you total answer to get the plates allowed.

Edit:
So you want all permutations of 0-9 in the first, fifth, sixth, and seventh positions. And all permutations of A-Z of the second, third and fourth positions, except for F in the second, S in the third and S in the fourth, right? If so, it would be 10*25*25*25*10*10*10, or 10^4 * 25^3. Did I get your problem right?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I meant that the # means digit, from 0-9.  So there are 1 digit, then 3 letters(The FSS would be excluded) and then followed up by another 3 digits between 0-9 of any combination.  But yeah, I understood your answer.  Just trying to include all combinations, except for the word "FSS".

Comment: I think I may have solved it.  I got your 1st answer.  #FSS### is 10,000 possibility.  Now, let's say every other combination I do with the California liscense is (10^4 * 26*3) = 175,760,000.  I simply subtract 10000, because there are 10,000 license plates that has the word "FSS", that I want to exclude.  That will be my answer!   Hope that made sense. But I appreciate your reply, it made me think the problem more analytically.

Comment: Can I get an upvote for your appreciation, if you aren't going to accept the answer?

Comment: It says I have to have 15 reputation points to up vote your answer >.<  I clicked the check though and accepted your answer :)